# django: How to put date value from database to "input type='date'"?

Tags: html, django

why is it i cant put value from my database to input type date? even though my query is correct?

```
{% for feedback in feedbacks %}
   <input name="datef" value="{{feedback.dateSubmitted}}" type="date">
{% endfor %}
```

this is my views.py

```
feedback = obj.objects.all()
    print(feedback)
```

this is the result for print

```
<QuerySet [<TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords: mystudent>]>
```

my models.py

```
class TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords(models.Model):
    .....
    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    .....
```

the result in my webview

[image]

UPDATE: i change my html to this , and this is the result in my webview

html

```
{% for feedback in feedbacks %}
    {{feedback.dateSubmitted}} <input name="datef" value="{{feedback.dateSubmitted}}" type="date">
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `{{feedback.dateSubmitted}}` have some value?

Comment: yeah, im pretty sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the formatting is off. The date input probably wants something like `year-month-date`. Try passing it like this:

```
<input name="datef" value="{{feedback.dateSubmitted|date:'Y-m-d'}}" type="date">
```

If the above doesn't work, also try:

```
<input name="datef" value="{{feedback.dateSubmitted|date:'d/m/Y'}}" type="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

for all user inputs i think it will be better to use django forms or ModelForms
after that django will format all values for you and it will be more cleaner way to validate user data, and save it to database. for multiple forms you can use [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

in view you create formset:

```
TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecordsFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords, 
    fields=('dateSubmitted ', )
)       
formset = TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecordsFormSet()
```

and add `formset` as parameter to your `html` template

and then in html template you can

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.dateSubmitted.value }} {{ form.dateSubmitted }}
    {% endfor %}
```